# Trying to make a cursor lock, not working for unknown reasons

Tags: python, pyautogui

Please help me, there is no errors the setDisabled is just not called whenever I press N after pressing H.
If anyone knows how to improve or fix, please help.
Code:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

enabled = False

def setDisabled(a):
    global enabled
    print 'setDisabled: ' + str(enabled)
    enabled = False
    print 'setDisabled: ' + str(enabled)
    resetMouse()

keyboard.on_release_key('n', setDisabled)

def resetMouse():
    global enabled
    print 'resetMouse: ' + str(enabled)
    if enabled is True:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1, 1, 0)
        resetMouse()
    else:
        print "no"

def setEnabled(a):
    global enabled
    print 'setEnabled: ' + str(enabled)
    enabled = True
    print 'setEnabled: ' + str(enabled)
    resetMouse()

keyboard.on_release_key('h', setEnabled)

resetMouse()
```

Comment: do you use Python2 ?  Do you see printed text when you run it in console/terminal?

Comment: you may have to run some loop to keep program running. If you don't run loop then program ends work and will not get any keys.

Comment: I have a solution to keep the program running, I just didn't include it as I thought it wasn't important. Yes, I run Python2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press `h` then `keyboard` runs `resetMouse` which runs again `resetMouse` and it runs again `resetMouse` so this functions never ends - you have recursion - and it never go back to `keyboard` and it can't check other keys.

You would have to run `resetMouse` in different way - ie. you can run it in loop which keeps program running. And `resetMouse` shouldn't run again `resetMouse` but this loop should run.

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

# --- functions ---    

def setDisabled(a):
    global enabled

    print('setDisabled: ' + str(enabled))
    enabled = False
    print('setDisabled: ' + str(enabled))

    #resetMouse()

def setEnabled(a):
    global enabled

    print('setEnabled: ' + str(enabled))
    enabled = True
    print('setEnabled: ' + str(enabled))

    #resetMouse()

def resetMouse():
    global enabled

    #print('resetMouse: ' + str(enabled))
    if enabled: # is True:
        pyautogui.moveTo(1, 1, 0)
    #else:
    #    print("no")

# --- main ---

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

enabled = False

keyboard.on_release_key('n', setDisabled)
keyboard.on_release_key('h', setEnabled)

while True:
    #time.sleep(1) # to use less CPU 
    resetMouse()
```